# Change value in userPrincipalName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need help with PowerShell to change multiple AD accounts with the wrong value in userPrincipalName.

Several users got more than one @ in the string. So how can I use a CSV with the affected user accounts and change remove the extra @?

Comment: Do you have a code you need help with or do you just want to know how to change the string? StackOverflow doesn't accommodate code requests.

Comment: Hi, want to know how to change the string. I have started up like this to collect the users :-)                                                                                                        get-aduser -filter {userPrincipalName -like '*@@*'} -Properties userPrincipalName | select Name, userPrincipalName
Need to know how to change to one @ on every affected accont

Comment: Edit your question with that snippet so that answer can be tailored to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Replace` to change it.

```
$string = "sometext@@@sometext"
$string.Replace("@@@", "@")
```

or

```
$string = ("sometext@@@sometext").Replace("@@@", "@")
```

To replace the `@` regardless of how many is in the string you can user Regex

```
$string = "sometext@@@sometext"
$symbolcount = ([regex]::Matches($string, "@")).count
if ($symbolcount -gt 1){
    $symbols = ([regex]::Matches($string, "@")).Value -join ""
    $string = $string.Replace($symbols,"@")
}
```

Note: this will work only if all of the strings have `@@@` in them.

See [this site](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! we got som users with up to 16 @

Comment: Thanks ShanayL !! This would be helpful for me :-)

Comment: no problem...don't forget to mark my answer it as the solution if it works for you.